# Считать число из списка

Tags: python

Как из списка типа `a=[ "t","R","5","8","4","y"]` считать число 584?

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i].isdigith():
        NewList.append(a[i])
print(int(“”.join(NewList)))
```

Как попроще это сделать?

Comment: `''.join([i for i in a if i.isdigit()])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a=[ "t","R","5","8","4","y"]
res = int("".join(el for el in a if el.isdigit()))

print(res)
```

Comment: Дополнение: в вопросе не указана информация о входных данных, но стоит учесть, что если в списке `a` НЕ будет цифр/чисел или список будет пустой, то при преобразовании пустой строки в целочисленный тип будет ошибка: `ValueError`.

Comment: @AlTheOne `int("" or 0)` ?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Можно и так выкрутиться. Проблема решаема, неясно только как именно нужно её решать: если нет значений, то 0 ? или сообщение определённое писать? Или кастомное исключение писать? Или вовсе не обрабатывать и не ориентироваться на это, т.к. на входе обязательно цифры/числа подадут.

Comment: Цифры точно есть. А как быть с таким списком? “a=list(“tg6hg567jhg54gGf32vb11j77t”)”? Сначала преобразовать в строку(если не одиночное число), потом добавить в новый список? На выходе в итоге мне надо получить “a=split(“ t g 6 h g 567 j h g 54 g”)” и тд, а потом умножить число, на следующую букву, но с этим я справлюсь

Comment: @Виталий В следующий раз как можно подробнее описывайте задачу. И себе и другим сделаете проще. Также, если ответ Danis Вам помог зачтите его как верный (галочка слева от его ответа).

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с `filter`:

```
print(int("".join(filter(str.isdigit, a))))
```